# Does the linqjs library have performance advantages over using a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a `html5` canvas game where i have a really big multidimensional array and i need to select a couple things out of it which i'm going to use further or remove.

Now i see three different ways to do this:

- Using a for-loop and iterate the whole array.
- Using the `array.prototype.filter()` method.
- Using the https://linqjs.codeplex.com library.

Now, i want to now which method is the fastest.

(Please correct me when i wrote some english faults, it's not my native language.)

Comment: Run performance measurements and decide for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance will differ between browsers and javascript engines so the best thing to do is actually use some performance tools and profile them all. Most modern browsers have excellent profiling tools build into the developer console.

That said, certain javascript engines optimize for different situations. Many of them have done a lot of tuning to make their loops run quickly and, for the most part, for loops can be seen as reasonably predictable. A for loop also has the advantage that you can break out of it early if, say, you only need to find a single item and that item happens to occur sooner in the array.

A filter, on the other hand, is even more predictable since the browser knows it will need to inspect every element in the array. This allows the engine to make certain assumptions and break up the work differently; Possibly even parallelize it, though most engines won't do that automatically.

As far as LINQjs, the performance is going to be, at best, equal to, or more likely, worse performance. The reason for this is that the library is generally going to be doing more work than running a loop or making a call to a filter. The additional logic, conversion, etc. results in more overhead.

The reason someone might choose LINQjs is not for performance reasons but for usability reasons. They want a familiar syntax for doing data transformations and consider their development time more valuable than the execution time of the software.